# Laravel Multi Domain Session

Tags: session, authentication, laravel, cross-domain, subdomain

I am not a superb developer, so I guess the problem I did run into is just to big for me.

I have a project where I have different subdomains for the current language. When I login a user it is logged only for the current subdomain. So when I login at "en.Aproject.com", and then go to "de.Aproject.com", the user will not be logged in. They don't share the session. I already tried to modify the 'domain' => null, in app/sessions.php. But when I change the value here the Login doesn't work at all. Then everytime a new Session-row is created in the DB and Laravel seems not to recognize them.

Is the current domain saved somehow in the session identifier? Is it possible to use one session for different domains? I found some stuff about OAuth and Single sign-on but I can not handle it by myself.

I was thinking about (when logging in and the credentials are correct) calling a script via Ajax, which should log in the user for all needed domains. But I would have to do the same for logging out.. And I will probably have a lot of domains. The project will have one base page and several subprojects (all with the different languages). Like this

mainproject.com

en.mainproject.com

de.mainproject.com

...

Aproject.com

en.Aproject.com

de.Aproject.com

...

Bproject.com

en.Bproject.com

de.Bproject.com

...

So it would just feel wrong to log in the user to like 20 different pages and create 20 sessions... It would feel better to just use one session for all of them.

Okay, I hope you understand the problem and someone already had the same problem and found a solution. Thanks!!!!!!!! greets. gerti

---

Background info.. I am using Laravel 4.2

Now I just tried something, maybe it helps someone. Actually point 2 is weird to me (see below)

I display these 3 things:

**Session::getId()**

**Auth::getName()**

**var_dump(Session::all())**

I display them on "de.Aproject.com". Here I am logged in.

And i display them on "en.Aproject.com"... Where I am still logged out (which I want to fix :D )

1. The value of Session::getId() is different on both sides. Thats the problem I guess, they should share the same.
2. The value of Auth::getName() is the same on both sides (login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc). Which I don't understand. Why does the second page have this value when i am not logged in?
3. The value of Session::all() is ["login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc"] => string(17) "test@test.de" on the first site, on the second its empty. Thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default Laravel authentication system uses cookies to manage the session, you actually need to login the user on each subdomain you're going to use. To avoid that, you can use another session driver like database.